# On ER Diagram, can I have a weak entity that's dependent on multiple entities?

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, entity-relationship, erd

I have an entity called "Account", it contains Username, Email, Password and some more attributes.

And I have 2 entities called "Applicant" and "Business_Owner"
The entity "Account" is dependent on these 2, because an Applicant can have an account, and a business owner can also have an account.
What's the logical design for it?

[image: "Account" entity on top]

Comment: So Account and Applicant have a 1:1 relationship, and so do Account and Business Owner. Is your question how to implement this? As a logical design it seems OK; what actually is your problem with it?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your diagram, I think what you have modelled is an `Account` that is dependable on both an `Applicant` and a `BusinessOwner`. From your description, this is not what you want.

One solution could be to model it using subtypes, with a basetype that has an account and two exclusive subtypes for your Applicant and Business owner.
For more information take a look at [this](https://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Article/Database/Relational%20Model/Subtype.pdf) document.

An example logical model:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You use an old representation, the one that Peter Chen used when he invented the concept of ERD I think. A 'weak' entity does not have its own identifier but its identifier comes from another entity (partially or totally). If 'account' groups the common fields together, which seems to be the case, there is a generalization with 'account' entity. I don't think P. Chen spoke about this concept, but weak entities, so to speak, would be 'Applicant' and 'Business_Owner' because they would have the account identifier, they do not have their own identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The assumption of a dependency that would require `Account` to be a weak entity is not founded.

An `Account` is an independent entity.  That entity is related to either an `Applicant` or a `Business_Owner`. It is by the way not clear if the same person behind the account could not endorse both roles at the same time.

You would model this with:

- two relationships `Account -- Applicant` and `Account -- Business_Owner`,
- the participation of `Applicant` and `Business_Owner` would be total (i.e. each business owner must have an account, and each applicant must have an account),
- the participation of the `Account` would be partial (i.e. it can have the one, the other or both, or none)
- the cardinality of each participation is 1

The drawback of this model is that it doesn't enforce the business rule that there must be (at least? at most?) one of the participation in the relationships mandatory. In more modern notations, like UML, this is easily possible via "constraints", but this does lot exist for ERD (be it in Chen's notation or in Craw's foot notatiin). But anyway, at the DB implementation level, you'd have to do this check programmatically, so the DB structure is fine.

**Not related to this question**: the relationship Review, which seem to have its own attributes should be an associative entity (ie. the diamond should be enclose in a rectangle. More on this notation [here](https://vertabelo.com/blog/chen-erd-notation/))